# How to run a program after another one returns true

Tags: exe

I have 2 exe file. **file1.exe** and **file2.exe** . I need a **file3.exe** which contains the first two files. When **file3** was run, the **file1** would run and if **file1** returns true, the **file2** will run. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a `.bat` file

```
file1.exe
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO error1
file2.exe
:error1
```